# Probable unrecognized buffer overflow

Tags: c, powershell, buffer, overflow

i'm working on a function which executes a specific powershell command and then returns the output if this is different from EOF. The function correctly executes the first time, but the second time the output is weird, signal that there is a buffer overflow in some part of my code. I can't find it. Otherwise, i wasn't able to figure out other possible solutions for this kind of behavior.

Here's the code:

```
char* buffer_reset(char* buffer);
bool jobsreader (const char* printer_name, char* buffer);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[1000];
    char* pbuffer = buffer;
    jobsreader("Microsoft Print to PDF", pbuffer);
    pbuffer = buffer_reset(pbuffer);
    jobsreader("Microsoft Print to PDF", pbuffer);
    return 0;
}

char* buffer_reset(char* buffer) {
    char* memory_reset = &buffer[0];
    char* start = memory_reset;
    while (*memory_reset != '\0') {
        *memory_reset = '\0';
        memory_reset++;
    }
    buffer = start;
    return buffer;
}

bool jobsreader (const char* printer_name, char* buffer) {
    FILE *output;
    const char* cmd = "powershell -Command Get-PrintJob '";
    int dim = (strlen(cmd)+1+strlen(printer_name)+1+2);
    char powershell[dim]; // + 1 per carattere \0 + 1 per carattere \0 + 2 per stringa "'\0"
    strcat(powershell, cmd);
    strcat(powershell, printer_name);
    strcat(powershell, "'");

    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%s\n", powershell);

    output = popen(powershell, "r"); // Esegue il comando shell e restituisce un puntatore a FILE
    if (output == NULL) {
        printf("Error in executing the command: are you sure this printer exists?\n");
        pclose(output); // Chiude il file
        return false;
    } else {
        char c;
        // Se c'è un processo in corso (quindi output della shell diverso da EOF)
        while ((c = getc(output)) != EOF) {
            *buffer = c;
            printf("%c", c); // Stampa a video del processo in corso
            buffer++;
        }
        printf("\n");

        *buffer = '\0';
        pclose(output); // Chiude il file
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output 1: powershell -Command Get-PrintJob 'Microsoft Print to PDF' (OK)
Output 2,3,4 ...: powershe@powershell -Command Get-PrintJob 'Microsoft Print to PDF' (WRONG)

May anybody help me?

I want to output and execute the following powershell command: Get-PrintJob <printer_name>

Comment: Can't compile your code: `error: unknown type name 'FILE'
    FILE *output;` Be kind to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem are these two lines:

```
char powershell[dim];
strcat(powershell, cmd);
```

The array isn't initialized, its contents is *indeterminate*.

More specifically, it can't be used as a null-terminated string, which is what `strcat` expects. Because of this you will have *undefined behavior*.

You must begin with a `strcpy` call instead:

```
strcpy(powershell, cmd);
```

---

Alternatively you could use `snprintf` instead of multiple `strcpy` and `strcat` calls:

```
snprintf(powershell, dim, "powershell -Command Get-PrintJob '%s'", printer_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always the same.  All C books explain this, which is a basic problem:

```
        char c;
        // Se c'è un processo in corso (quindi output della shell diverso da EOF)
        while ((c = getc(output)) != EOF) {
```

`EOF` is an `int` constant and `c` must be declared `int`.  the reason is that `getc()` returns `0` to `255` for each `char` input, and the extra value `EOF` (warranted not to be any of the other 256 values)

As a `char` is allowed only 256 values, it is not possible to have them all and the extra `EOF` which is warranted to be none of them.  `getc()` returns `int` and so `c` must be declared `int c;` and not `char c; /* bad */`